# jQuery.Swiper.js pagination not working, how to setup?

Tags: html, jquery, swiper.js

Slider works but pagination is not visible

HTML:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img class="swiper-img" src="/assets/img.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img class="swiper-img" src="/assets/img.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img class="swiper-img" src="/assets/img.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img class="swiper-img" src="/assets/img.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
        pagination: {
          el: ".swiper-pagination",
          clickable: true,
          renderBullet: function (index, className) {
            return '<span class="' + className + '">' + "</span>";
          },
        },
      });
    })
```

[image]

The scripts are connected, the slider works. But we see that there is simply no pagination, and it's not about styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `<div class="swiper-pagination"></div>` outside the scope of `<div class="swiper-container">`

Have a look at this code on jsfiddle that I wrote for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/udf82qaw/

Comment: It's inside the swiper-container..

Comment: But thank you very much! I understood what the problem is. I used swiper.jquery.min.js, now I used swiper.bundle.min.js and it worked!

Comment: @ТахирМухаметов You've probably missed out one `</div>` while copying and pasting your code here and that's what I've noticed immediately. 

Even though my answer wasn't pointing at the actual problem, I am glad that it helped you to meet your requirements. 
Please, next time when posting something like this also paste your CDN links and what libraries you use.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="height:100%">
<div class="swiper swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">IMAGE 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">IMAGE 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">IMAGE 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">IMAGE 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">IMAGE 5</div>
  </div>    
</div>
   <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.